# firebase_storage/unauthorized User is not authorized to perform the desired action

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-app-check

I have Flutter mobile app with Firebase in the backend.  I am using Firebase cloud storage with the following security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{uid}/{fileId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I am also using App Check.
When running the app with Firebase emulator, I can upload and delete images with no issues. However, when I place the app in the Play Store, I can upload an image but when I delete an image, I get this exception:

```
[firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.
```

I know for sure that the user is already signed in.
Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I went to google cloud console / cloud storage, then clicked on my bucket name, then clicked on protection tab. I found that I had a retention policy that disallow deleting objects in the bucket.  Once I deleted the retention policy, everything started working again.